# How to capture xpath of a button on a web page

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to capture xpath of an element for an automation script but unable to capture the exact one as my script is failing everytime when it tries to click quick view

Any suggestions please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, you can get XPath and CSS selector with :

> In first tab of the Web Development Tool (F12) > Right click on your html element > Copy > Copy XPath or Copy Selector

[image: Get Xpath selector in Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ad-dons firebug in Firefox and `xpath` checker in chrome. Just inspect the element you get the locator values

xpath of your element: `//button[contains(text(),'Quick view')]`

Comment: Thanks much, this helped.

Comment: I tried using xpath helper in Chrome and Firebug in firefox but nothing is capturing the correct xpath for this particular button.